# Cannot plot from .gplot file with multiple commands in tikz for LaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, texstudio, gnuplot

I am currently writing my bachelor thesis with TexStudio and Miktex on a Windows 10 machine. I have to use gnuplot which I have .gplot files and .data files for. The .gplot files contain the settings for the plot, the .data files contain the required data. When using the Gnuplot terminal I can plot data just fine.
After a lot of trying I found out, that I need to replace the 'set...' commands and adjust the plot command for some reason. Still, if I compile my LaTex to an PDF (all plots are loaded into tikz) I get an empty box where the plot should be when there is more than one 'set...' command in the .gplot file. In the console I always find some statement of how the next command listed in the .gplot file is unexpected or invalid.

The .gplot file with adjusted plot command is to be seen here:

```
set title 'Rudder Stock Mom.'
set xlabel "Rudder Angle \n " 
set ylabel 'M_{STOCK} [kNm]'
set x2label ''
set y2label ''
set xrange [-44:44]
set yrange [-7500:10000]
set x2range [-48.400002:48.400002]
set y2range [-7036.790527:9586.032227]
set xtics border autofreq mirror norotate 
unset x2tics
set ytics border norotate autofreq mirror 
unset y2tics
unset logscale x
unset logscale x2
unset logscale y
unset logscale y2
unset xzeroaxis
unset yzeroaxis
set grid lw 1.200
set key bmargin center box horizontal reverse Left
set palette model RGB defined ( 1 'black', 2 'grey', 3 'dark-grey', 4 'dark-yellow', 5 'yellow', 6 'orange', 7 'light-red', 8 'red', 9 'dark-red', 10 'purple', 11 'navy', 12 'blue', 13 'cyan', 14 'light-blue', 15 'brown', 16 'green', 17 'dark-green', 18 'white')
set cbrange [1:18]
unset colorbox
set dashtype 6  '- '
set dashtype 7  '. '
set dashtype 8  '--.'
set dashtype 9  '--..'
set dashtype 10 '_ '
set dashtype 11 '_-'
set dashtype 12 '.._'
set dashtype 13 '_.'
set dashtype 14 '_'
set dashtype 15 '_ .. '
set boxwidth 0.7 relative
set style fill solid
plot 'C:/Users/.../fig/gnuplot/RudderStockMom15.data' index 0 using 1:2 axes x1y1 title ' CTH =        14.547' dt 1 lc rgbcolor "red" lw 1.0 with lines ,\
'C:/Users/.../fig/gnuplot/RudderStockMom15.data' index 1 using 1:2 axes x1y1 title ' CTH =         5.551' dt 1 lc rgbcolor "orange" lw 1.0 with lines ,\
'C:/Users/.../fig/gnuplot/RudderStockMom15.data' index 2 using 1:2 axes x1y1 title ' CTH =         3.188' dt 1 lc rgbcolor "green" lw 1.0 with lines ,\
'C:/Users/.../fig/gnuplot/RudderStockMom15.data' index 3 using 1:2 axes x1y1 title ' CTH =         1.886' dt 1 lc rgbcolor "cyan" lw 1.0 with lines ,\
'C:/Users/.../fig/gnuplot/RudderStockMom15.data' index 4 using 1:2 axes x1y1 title ' CTH =         1.325' dt 1 lc rgbcolor "blue" lw 1.0 with lines
```

```
\begin{figure}%
    \centering%
    \tikzsetfigurename{RudderStockMom15}    % Important: Always set this variable for TikZ figures, so that externalized figures are named correctly
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \gnuplotloadfile[terminal=tikz, terminaloptions=color nopicenvironment]{./fig/gnuplot/RudderStockMom15.gplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Veränderung des Rudermoments am Stock Rudder über verschiedene Anstellwinkel.}
    \label{pic:RudderStockMom15}%
\end{figure}%
```

The question is why the standard format for gnuplot will not work and how I can adjust the file to get all the settings into the resulting PDF.

Comment: Hi Henri, it seems that your figures are stored in subfolders. Have you tried adding `\graphicspath{{fig/}{fig/gnuplot/}}` to your preamble?

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, thank you for your reply! I have now tried it but I still get the same error. By now I copied the .data file to multiple folders like my C:/ , data and gnuplot directories just to see where the program would finde the data. I also tried putting the entire path of the .data file into the plot command in .gplot but that also didn't give any new results. If the .gplot file is loaded as now edited into the original question, in which directory will the data be searched for?

Comment: Sorry had to install `gnuplot`. For Windows, one directory is `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`. You can find more information by typing `help startup` in a `gnuplot` console. It looks like `gnuplottex` executes `gnuplot` command without changing the default directory.